# Setting textAlign on a per line basis of a text/iText/textbox object

Tags: fabricjs

Setting textAlign on a per line basis of a text/iText/textbox object

I would like to set separate text align for every line of a text/iText/textbox object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that currently. Subrange styles are set characters by character and even if you give every character in a line the same textAlign it does not effect how the text is laid out. textAlign only work on the whole object.

```js
window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false, preserveObjectStacking:true });

canvas.add(new fabric.IText(`some text
here on
multiple lines`,{ 
  left: 100, 
  top: 100, 
  fill: 'red', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true,
  textAlign: 'center',
  styles: {
   0: {
     0: { fill: 'blue', textAlign: 'right' },
     1: { fill: 'blue', textAlign: 'right' },
     2: { fill: 'blue', textAlign: 'right' },
     3: { fill: 'blue', textAlign: 'right' },
     4: { fill: 'green', textAlign: 'right' },
     5: { fill: 'green', textAlign: 'right' },
     6: { fill: 'green', textAlign: 'right' },
     7: { fill: 'green', textAlign: 'right' },
     8: { fill: 'green', textAlign: 'right' }
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```